# I got Stripe \ PermissionException error with new stripe api keys

Tags: stripe-payments

Working with Stripe Connect  and making :

```
\Stripe\Charge::create
```

I got error :

```
Stripe \ Exception \ PermissionException
The provided key 'sk_test_51*************************************************
********************************************AE7z' does not have access to account 'acct_NNNN' 
(or that account does not exist). Application access may have been revoke
```

My code worked with different stripe account, but I need to set api keys of my client
After logtin into stripe with credentials of my client I just activated the the Stripe connect,
but looks like not all settings are set: https://prnt.sc/10vfict

1. Which steps have I to take next ?
2. I wrote to support under my client credentials, but my client not
   alwaysa available and as I have no acccess to his email account I ask if there is a
   way to read messages from support in stripe dashboard? I did not find such possibility...

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you didn't actually connect the two accounts to one another. Assuming you're using Standard connect, here's how you do that: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#how-to-use-connect-onboarding-for-standard-accounts

Comment: Have you managed to resolve it?

Comment: No, I did not salve it